# Pipeline/Filter <br/> tags in Text through AngularJs Pipeline

Tags: angularjs, filter, pipeline

I have addresses stored in text format which include 
 tags within them to separate Street Address from City and State with a New line between the two 
How can I pipeline/filter the address text to remove 
 tags within the text?

For Example
This removes spaces 
{{Address | EliminateSpaces}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write a custom filter and use it

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.textExample ='address sample <br/> <br> text';

  $scope.textFilteredInController = $filter('removeBreakTags') ($scope.textExample);
});

app.filter('removeBreakTags', function() {
 return function(text) {
  return  text ? String(text).replace(/<br\s*\/?>/gm, '') : '';
 };
});
 
app.filter('removeHTMLTags', function() {
 return function(text) {
  return  text ? String(text).replace(/<br\s*\/?>/, '') : '';
 };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<p>{{ textExample | removeHTMLTags }}</p> 

<p>{{ textExample | removeBreakTags }} </p>  

<p> --- In Controller ---</p>

<p>{{textFilteredInController}}</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply and formidable insight 
How can I achieve the result as in filter the text in my controller

Comment: I update my answer to show you how to show you how to use the filter in the controller.

Comment: if my answer sufficient for you , kindly upvote and mark it as correct answer, thank you.